# phpMyAdmin error 500 when using navigation tree

Tags: phpmyadmin

Recently, I get error 500 when I try to select a different page in the navigation tree of phpMyAdmin. Another error that I notice is that the 'Get auto-saved query' feature does not work anymore. My website is hosted by a hosting provider, so I have no responsability for, nor access to the installation of phpMyAdmin. But my hosting provider simply does not seem to care to solve the problems. If someone has any idea how to solve these issues, I could suggest this to my hosting provider. The current installed version of phpMyAdmin is 5.0.1.

**Edit:** only today (after two weeks) my hosting provider went back to version 4.9.4, which solved the problems.

Comment: That's impossible to fix an *error 500* (which is just a code telling there is an error server-side) without knowing the real reason behind. (Check logs)

Comment: Someone might recognize these symptoms. The error is a popup window by the way.

Comment: Perhaps your issue is https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15772 or https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15756 ? Both of those are fixed and will be part of the next release (5.0.2).